# Phonegap - running executeSql within ajax call results in INVALID_STATE_ERROR

Tags: ajax, cordova, jsonp

I'm working on a project in wich i get specific users from my server database and insert the userdata in the local phone database. I'm doing this with a ajax(jsonp) request within a transaction (see code). If i run this code it'll give me an INVALID_STATE_ERROR.

I've tried wrapping the tx.executeSql in a db.transaction (within the success of the ajax call) this gets rid of the INVALID_STATE_ERROR but it wont insert any data.

Help!

The transaction code:

```
db.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userdata');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdata (id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY, name)');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://[myserver]/getUser.php',
            type: 'get',
            data: {'user': enteredUser, 'pass': enteredPass},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: "application/json",
            jsonpCallback: 'getUser',
            /*async: false,*/
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status) {

                //alert(data.name);

                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO userdata (id, name) VALUES (' + data.id + ', "' + data.name + '")');



            },
            error: function(a, b, c){

               alert('Update Failed: ' + a.status);
               alert('Update Failed: ' + c);
            }
        });

    }, 
    onNoUser,
    function()
    {
        db.transaction(checkLogin, showLogin);
    });
```

if more code or info is needed, let me know!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem ("InvalidStateError") but creating a new transaction inside the AJAX callback solved my problem. Inserting data into the database also works fine.

Try to log the error inside the onError callback

```
tx.executeSql(sqlStatement, dataArray, onSuccess, function(tx, err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Maybe another error occurs that prevents the data from being written into the database.